Equivalent definitions of outer regularity
I proved the following equivalences, however there's a chance that I did some mistakes. Therefore, I'd would like to know if the following equivalences are in fact true. I won't provide the proofs of the equivalences since they're very long. However, if someone is interested in how I proved any of the following equivalences, tell me and I'll write what I did.
Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mu :\mathfrak{B}_X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a finite measure with $\mathfrak{B}_X$ being the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. Then we have the following equivalences:

$\mu$ is outer regular, i.e., for all $B\in\mathfrak{B}_X$ we have $\mu (B)=\inf \{\mu (U):B\subseteq U\wedge U\text{ is open}\}$;
For all $B\in \mathfrak{B}_X$ and $\varepsilon >0$ there's an open set $U\subseteq X$ such that $B\subseteq U$ and $\mu (U\setminus B)<\varepsilon $;
For all $B\in \mathfrak{B}_X$ and $\varepsilon >0$ there're a closed set $F\subseteq X$ and an open set $U\subseteq X$ such that $F\subseteq B\subseteq U$ and $\mu (U\setminus F)<\varepsilon $;
For all $B\in \mathfrak{B}_X$ and $\varepsilon >0$ there's a closed set $F\subseteq X$ such that $F\subseteq B$ and $\mu (B\setminus F)<\varepsilon $;
For all $B\in\mathfrak{B}_X$ we have $\mu (B)=\sup \{\mu (F):F\subseteq B\wedge F\text{ is closed}\}$.

Please, confirm if the previous equivalences are in fact true. I looked at some books but I couldn't find any theorem confirming that they're true and that's why I'm a bit uncertain about the validity of my proofs (sometimes I make mistakes that are hard to find).

Seems good to me.
